# How i can Do an action in another activity ?android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 activities  ,activity A is having webview and activity B is having button with transparent layout. I want  close the activity B and refresh or do something in activity A when I press button from activity B. 
I tried shared preferences but that not working without restarting activity A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the docs for [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

**Updated to include example**

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
...
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much  lsaac Payne

Comment: Thanks Simo and lsaac

Answer (score -1):

create a method as refreshmethod in Activity A and call it from Activity B something like this:

```
ActivityA activitya:
//stuff
activitya = new ActivityA();
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            activitya.refreshmethod();
        }
    });
```

hope it helps.

Comment: You can't use new on an Activity (it will compile, but not work).  Even if you could, doing so would create a new ActivityA, not reference the existing one.

Comment: u mean "new" inside an activity or with an activity?

Comment: With an Activity.  new ActivityA will create an object, but it won't start an Activity, and it won't be the same as a previously launched version of ActivityA.